# Run Reg Query against list of computers

Tags: windows

How would I run the command below on a list of computers and have the results include the value and PC name.

Right now it does return the value but only runs locally

```
FOR /F "tokens=2* skip=2" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" /v "CommonFilesDir"') do echo %%b
```

Comment: You need to use [PsExec - Execute process remotely - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) and run `req query` on the remote machines

Comment: `psexec` is part of [Sysinternals Suite - Sysinternals | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be something like this?

```
psexec @C:\_\complist.txt FOR /F "tokens=2* skip=2" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" /v "CommonFilesDir"') do echo %%b
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).